# Hiding the SlickGrid filters for certain field

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am very new to javascript . I was working in a application where i need to use the slick grid with the filter . i was following this link 
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html .
in my app , i dont want filter to be in all fields , only for certain field i need .

could anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.grid.onHeaderRowCellRendered.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    $(args.node).empty();
    if(args.column.id == 'name' || args.column.id == 'contract'){
        var s = $("<input type='text'>");
        s.data('columndata', args.column.id)
        .val(columnFilters[args.column.id])
        .appendTo(args.node);
        console.log(s);
    };
    });
```

will appear only for columns with id 'name' and 'contract'